# How to thicken grass

Tags: lawn, grass, seeds, fertilizer

I live in Massachusetts and I'm trying to get my grass greener. My grass has many spots that are thin and light green. Also, there are some spots about the size of a basketball that are just a big empty spot with nothing growing. Other spots are thicker and also a deeper green color which is what I want. In some spots I can see visibly a line of where different grasses are. Maybe the type of grass is different or it was seeded at a differne time with different seeds. I'm not sure. How can I get my spots that don't grow thick to grow thicker and greener? I've already applied **Scotts® Turf Builder® Halts Crabgrass Preventer with Lawn Food** about 3 weeks ago on about 11,000 square feet of lawn. I also dethatched before that. Do I need to just keep waiting and do my normal watering and mowing? Do I need to overseed? I read on the Scotts website in the reviews that there is only a 2% chance that overseeding on existing grass will do anything. Do I need to target specific seeds? So I need to apply a grub preventer? Most of my lawn faces east and gets a lot of light. Some of the lawn faces south as well and gets a lot of light too. The opposite side on the north does not and have a lot of spots of dark thick green grass and tons of moss. I'm asking because I moved into this new house so I have not cared for this lawn before.

(click images below for larger size)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here's a good link since it sounds like your root system isn't deep enough: http://www.pennington.com/resources/grass-seed/grass-101/recommended-grasses-for-regional-climates

Comment: Adding a picture of the lawn would be very helpful as well.

Comment: I've added two images of the lawn

Answer (score 1):

You need to aerate your lawn.  Once the plugs are removed, you can then fill in the holes with a top soil that is high in sand.   Once you have the holes filled you can over seed.  The seed will grow in these spots where it does not have to compete with other grass.   The other option is not to over seeds.  It will not take very long for your current grass to fill in these open patches.  This will bring new life to your lawn.

[Aeration and over-seeding - Turf Magazine](https://www.turfmagazine.com/lawn-care/comparing-aeration-overseeding-techniques/)